# Not working is_author(get_current_user_id()) in functions wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I have problem to apply a post_type for users who have created their post, in theory I found those functions of wordpress, but apparently it does not work

```
function preview_publish_posts($query) { 
    if( is_user_logged_in() && is_author(get_current_user_id()) ) {
        $query->set('post_status', array('publish', 'pending'));
    }
    return $query;
}

add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'preview_publish_posts');
```

Or it is possible that the function is not valid for calling it from functions.php

Comment: If i'm not mistaken, is_author() without parameter -> when any Author page is being displayed.  is_author()  with a parameter will only check if an author archive page is being displayed, Is that what you want to do ?

Comment: I'm having a very similar problem to you. When I remove the get_current_user_id() it works on all author pages perfectly, but I only want it to work on the currently logged in author's page. Also I don't think you need to use "return $query" for this to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of playing around I found that no matter how I tried is_author(get_current_user_id()) would never return true. I checked to see if that was the fault of get_current_user_ID, but this would return the correct value. I ended up using a slightly different method to achieve the desired result.

The code below fixed the problem for me, however I would still like to know why is_author(get_current_user_id()) doesn't work in this case.

```
function preview_publish_posts($query) {

    $curauth = (get_query_var('author_name')) ? get_user_by('slug', get_query_var('author_name')) : get_userdata(get_query_var('author'));

    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && is_author() ){
        if( is_user_logged_in() && $curauth->ID == get_current_user_id() ) {        
            $query->set( 'post_status', array('publish', 'pending'));
        }
        return;
    } 
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'preview_publish_posts' );
```