# How to add dash or character between two function? (PHP Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm newbie in PHP Wordpress :)

I added 'Edit' and 'Delete' button in my post.

Edit and delete function are valid for admin and the author of post only.

```
<?php edit_post_link('Edit'); ?> <?php delete_post(); ?>
```

The result is "EditDelete"

How can I add bar between edit and delete to make it "Edit | Delete"?

I need your help. Thank you :D

Comment: `<?php edit_post_link('Edit'); ?> | <?php delete_post(); ?>`? Or replace | with - or whatever.

Comment: Everything you put outside a block enclosed by PHP markers `<?php` and `?>` is sent directly to the browser. Try to stick the `|` between the two blocks and see what happens.

Comment: Thank you for your help.I did, but if users logged out, the bar is left only. The function "Edit" and "Delete" is only for logged in user&& the author of post.

Comment: @hiyo update your question so that it indicates you need this shown only to logged in users (and also users that are not the author of the page/post they are viewing). That way the question (and it's correct answers) will be easier to find in future for people with the same problem. Thank you and good luck with your project!

Comment: @WilliamPatton Got it, thank you. I edited my question.

Comment: perfect, I'll remove my other comments :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use like below (in wordpress):-

we can use is_page() method to check page or not.

```
<?php if( is_user_logged_in() && is_author(get_current_user_id() && is_page()) {?>
    <?php edit_post_link('Edit'); ?> | <?php delete_post(); ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thank you, however the code <?php if( is_user_logged_in() && is_author(get_current_user_id()) {?> is not working on my server. When I upload this php, nothing is displayed.

Comment: <?php edit_post_link('edit'); ?> It does not need below code : "<?php if( is_user_logged_in() && is_author(get_current_user_id())" Should I put in these code for a bar?

Comment: Which file you are trying this script? You mean to say bar is sidebar?

Comment: I'm trying to put this script in post layout(near title section). I meant, Bar(Dash) means between Edit and Delete.. Edit button and delete  button works perfectly for author and admin, but only bar is problem.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/tLErN The problem is bar between edit and delete. It's left when I logged out. REF : http://imgur.com/a/phK6J

Comment: Can you give that script which you tried in post layout? which file you placed that script?

Comment: You just need to add this condition, this will validate user is logged in or not?

<?php if( is_user_logged_in() && is_author(get_current_user_id()) {?>
    <?php edit_post_link('Edit'); ?> | <?php delete_post(); ?>
<?php } ?>

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/4eiNt single-meta-compact.php which is for post layout under theme folder.

Comment: If I add the code <?php if( is_user_logged_in() && is_author(get_current_user_id()) {?> the post becomes white(nothing) The code is not working, I would like to know the reason.

Comment: This both functions returns below response,
is_user_logged_in() --> True if user is logged in, false if not logged in.
get_current_user_id() --> The current user's ID

Comment: If I add those codes in my php file, it becomes like this : http://imgur.com/a/WYRUQ The content is not displayed at all.

Comment: You better try with below script, without is_author(),

<?php if( is_user_logged_in() && get_current_user_id()) {?>
    <?php edit_post_link('Edit'); ?> | <?php delete_post(); ?>
<?php } ?>

Comment: Thank you for your help. For better understanding, I had added delete function before those code "<?php
function delete_post(){
    global $post;
    $deletepostlink= add_query_arg( 'frontend', 'true', get_delete_post_link( get_the_ID() ) );
    if (current_user_can('edit_post', $post->ID)) {
        echo       '<span><a class="post-delete-link" onclick="return confirm(\'Are you sure to delete?\')" href="'.$deletepostlink.'">Delete</a></span>';
    }
}"

Comment: Praba, the codes you gave me is working! " <?php if( is_user_logged_in() && get_current_user_id()) {?> <?php edit_post_link('Edit'); ?> | <?php delete_post(); ?> <?php } ?>" Gotcha :D :D :D

Comment: Thank you so much! Could you explain me that the code is not working at all? "<?php if( is_user_logged_in() && is_author(get_current_user_id()"? Actually, I tried this code a few days ago, however, the code is not working.

Comment: Hiyo, Cheers. Seems the problem is with this method,  is_author(get_current_user_id())

Comment: Yeah Cheers! Adding bar is too difficult. :( Is this way the best and optimal way to add bar between function? I'm newbie so I would like to find the best way. I thought that it would work like this code : <?php edit_post_link('Edit') .'ㅣ'. delete_post(); ?> Can I make those codes be shorter or not?

Comment: Yes. when you logged out this will not display, if the below code works fine,

<?php if( is_user_logged_in() && get_current_user_id()) {?> 
<?php edit_post_link('Edit') .'ㅣ'. delete_post(); ?>
 <?php } ?>

Comment: How about this code? <?php
 $edit = edit_post_link('Edit');
 $del = delete_post();
?>
 
<?= "$edit ㅣ $del" ?>

Comment: I hope this will work,
<?php if( is_user_logged_in()){ ?>
<?php $edit = edit_post_link('Edit'); $del = delete_post(); ?>
 <?php $edit ㅣ $del ?>
<?php } ?>

Comment: Thank you again Praba! I think the first code you gave me is the best. Have a nice day! Cheers!

Comment: Cheers! Hiyo. You too.

Answer (score 2):

Do like below (in wordpress):-

```
<?php if( is_user_logged_in() && is_author(get_current_user_id()) {?>
    <?php edit_post_link('Edit'); ?> | <?php delete_post(); ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thank you. However, "<?php if( is_user_logged_in() && is_author(get_current_user_id()) {?>" this code is not working. :( I found the similar case : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40809343/not-working-is-authorget-current-user-id-in-functions-wordpress I wonder why it is not working.